# A word to describe a person that is solely responsible for all of the problems (like "causer" but not exactly)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I'm looking for an English word I knew beforehand but now I've forgotten!

The root of the word pertains to the word "cause". It's also a noun that refers to "persons".

Let's look upon it, as an example:

You tell a someone: You're the causer of all of these problems. ("causer" is not the word I'm looking for, but close to it and with the same meaning)

Actually, we use that noun to say the reason for the problems is that person solely, and he is guilty/responsible for all of them.

The synonym names close to it are:
*Cause*, *responsible*, *reason* and son on.
Now do you know what word it was, please?

If you mention it, I'll quickly recall it.

Comment: Have you tried the Oxford Thesaurus? https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/responsible https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/culprit

Comment: @RubioRic, Yes, I tried it for those two words plus "cause". I couldn't find the word I'm looking for unfortunately.

Comment: Here are some more http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/culprit?s=t

Comment: And what about "accused"?

Comment: Maybe you're talking about the word **causality**? That's the only word I can think of that shares the same root with the word *cause* and is similar to *cause* in meaning. On the other hand, **causality** has nothing to do with people. Or maybe you're talking about the word **culprit** as RubioRic has mentioned in his comment?

Comment: @RubioRic, thank you for your efforts to help me. :)

Comment: @MichaelRybkin, yes, your right. Let's look upon it with this explanation: The person is the solely reason for the work. What he/she did may not be a crime either.What he/she did is the real and direct reason for the work/problem.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Maybe is not what OP's looking for but "accused" fits very well his requirements: accuse "from Latin accusare ‘call to account’, from ad- ‘towards’ + causa ‘reason, motive, lawsuit’". It shares the same root: causa. Latin rocks! ;-P

Comment: How about **source**?

Comment: I would say "It's all your fault."

Comment: Let's ask this question: What do you native English speakers each explicitly say as close as possible to what we were talking about, to such a person? "*You're the ... of all of these difficulties*."

Comment: Is the word *catalyst*?

Comment: What about "instigator".

Answer (score 1):

Typically when people say "You're the x of all of these problems", the x is typically "**root**"

> **root**
>
> You're the **root** of all of these problems.

[**the source or origin of a thing**:
The love of money is the root of all evil. (definition 7)](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/root)

Alternatively, you could be referring to "origin","source", or "mastermind"

Answer (score 0):

The word you may be looking for to call the person who causes all your **bad problems** is

> **jinx**
>
> He is a **jinx** to us and everyone he meets.

Comment: "Jinx" has always seemed to me to define someone consistently associated with bad luck. If a sailor has survived three shipwrecks, others may consider him a jinx, but he is not considered to have caused the weather. This may be wrong; I have never quite grasped the "logic" of magic.

Answer (score 0):

One word that fits the bill is "culprit." Other words are "cause" or "source." It is perfectly good English to say "You are the cause of these problems." A phrase that works is "you are to blame."